# How do I upgrade an RDS instance's PostgreSQL version using TerraForm?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, terraform

My current RDS instance is running PostgreSQL version 9.6.3, but I'd like to upgrade it to version 10.1. However, when I set the new version number in my TerraForm configuration and set [`allow_major_version_upgrade`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#allow_major_version_upgrade) to true, I run into the following error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_instance.db_instance: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_instance.db_instance: Error modifying DB Instance db-example: InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot find upgrade path from 9.6.3 to 10.1.
  status code: 400, request id: <id>
```

In fact, I get a similar error message when I set 9.6.4 as the new version number - which already is confusing, since `auto_minor_version_upgrade` is also set to true, yet the instance is still at 9.6.3.

As you can see, there's still a lot of RDS and PostgreSQL I have to come to grips with, so any background info that can help me understand the problem would be very welcome as well.

---

**Edit:**

After setting *just* `allow_major_version_upgrade` to true without actually modifying the version resulted in this error:

```
* aws_db_instance.db_instance: Error modifying DB Instance db-example: InvalidParameterCombination: No modifications were requested
```

Comment: Did you apply `allow_major_version_upgrade` and then tried to apply upgrade or did you do them both at once?

Comment: @JakubKania Both at once - should they be applied sequentially? (And if so, I presume `allow_major_version_upgrade` should go first?)

Comment: Yes, please try that.

Comment: @JakubKania Unfortunately, TerraForm seems to demand both changes to be made at once - see my edit.

Comment: Where are you seeing support for Postgres 10.1 in RDS? The latest I see is `9.6.5`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Aargh... So that's part of the things I've got to come to grips with - I didn't know that and feel really dumb for not checking that now. I'll write that down as an answer, unless you write one, then I'll accept that.

Comment: Your answer covers it fairly, upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

As @ydaetskcoR pointed out, you can only upgrade to PostgreSQL versions actually supported by RDS, [which is `9.6.5` at the moment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.DBVersions).

The upgrade from 9.6.3 to 9.6.5 as a result of `auto_minor_version_upgrade` will also not happen as soon as it is supported, as described in an email Amazon sent a while ago:

> Beginning January 22 2018, if your database instances have the “Auto Minor Version Upgrade” option enabled, we will automatically upgrade your PostgreSQL database instances, using the same scheme mentioned above, during your maintenance window. If you do not wish to apply these upgrades at this point in time, please set the “Auto Minor Version Upgrade” option to "No" before January 20, 2018.